# Push notification preferences

Tags: react-native, chat, getstream-io

We need to allow a user to set specific preferences for receiving push notifications. Examples:

1. mute specific channel
2. send push only when @mentioned (global and
   chat specificly)

docs https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#push_ios doesn't cover it at all. Seems only turn on/off all notifications is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not supported by Stream Chat, improvements to the Push capabilities are added regularly so extended support for mutes and mentions will also come up soon enough.

In the meantime you can achieve this by handling chat events via webhooks and add the mute/mention logic on your webhook handler. More information about this can be found in the docs: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#webhook_events

Comment: How would this work? Are you saying that a push notication can be suppressed or added via webhook? Or are you just suggesting NOT using Stream Chat for the push notification and using the webhook to then send push notification instructions to a different push service?

Comment: if you have complex logic (or something that's not supported by Stream Chat) for sending push notifications you are better off building a web-hook handler and integrate with APNS/Firebase directly