# Can getstream.io push notifications be configured per message?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm using getstream.io chat and have wired up push notifications. However, as far as I've found in the docs it's all or nothing, especially from the admin side.

I'm wondering if any of these are possible and if so how to achieve them:

- When sending a message, configure whether it should trigger a push notification or not (right now, once push is set up, ALL messages seem to trigger push)...  [There's a "silent" parameter documented](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/silent_messages/?language=js) but it doesn't seem to silence push notifications
- Configure some channels to have push and others not to have push (mostly to work around the absence of the previous if that's not possible)
- Specify a push template to be used for one type of message versus another. I see how to change the push template globally but can different messages use different templates?

Note: most of our scenarios are around configuring a channel where there are many message readers and few senders- staff/admin users.

I [saw another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856985/push-notification-preferences) where they say this can be achieved by using webhooks to modify the message, but there's no indication of how this could work (short of just using the webhook to learn of needing to send a push notification and doing that via a separate system).

Answer (score 1):

v2 of push is coming which does all of above. However, it's not there today so workarounds in v1:

1. Silent does it, please contact support to enable (give app or org id).
2. Via 1, not needed
3. Not possible.

v2 helps a lot because it brings full customization of events and rendering to SDK and user preferences to snooze. ETA is this month.